# How do I correctly handle errors like these in SQLite/Java/Android?

Tags: java, android, sqlite, error-handling

For example I have something like this:

```
public void saveFoodatas(List<Foodata> foodataList) {
    DatabaseHelper.database.beginTransaction();
    try {
        for (Foodata foodata : foodataList) {
            saveFoodata(foodata);
        }
        DatabaseHelper.database.setTransactionSuccessful();
    }
    finally {
        DatabaseHelper.database.endTransaction();
    }
}
```

Where `DatabaseHelper` is a class extending `SQLiteOpenHelper` and `database` is a `SQLiteDatabase`.

In this function I am trying to make it so you save/commit a lot of objects to the database, but if there is a failure, then don't commit any of the changes.

I believe that what it's currently set up to do correctly (if there is an error, it leaves the `try` block I think and goes straight to `finally` since there is no `catch`), but my question is how to properly trigger the failure condition. Do I need `saveFoodata` to "throw an exception"? If the function encounters some kind of failure without me doing any try/catch/throwing, does that count too? How exactly do I handle `saveFooData()`?

Answer (score 0):

I think you are on the right track. You need to abort the transaction if an error occurs. You also need to alert the user of the problem. This means that `saveFoodata()` and `saveFoodatas()` should throw an exception so that the UI code can display a message to the user,

Comment: That's what I am trying to understand. What's the difference between having an error occur in `saveFoodata` that I didn't intend/foresee/do anything about in my code? Will those errors halt the app? If I do decide to account for them somehow, how do I abort the transaction / throw the exception?

Comment: @user6872907 If any method call from saveFoodata() throws a checked exception then you will get a compile error. On the other hand if any throw a runtime exception, your app will crash.

Comment: @user6872907 The try...finally is exactly the correct way to clean up in case of an error. Any method which calls saveFoodatas() needs to catch any exceptions that may occur.

Comment: In this case SQLException is a runtime exception.

Comment: Checked exception = something we've anticipated ahead of time and programmed alt-cases for, unchecked exception = something that happens at runtime we didn't foresee? (I've read many threads on checked vs unchecked exceptions but no one seems to be able to explain it in simple terms)

Comment: Is an error checked if it throws something in the function signature (which I believe is the same as "bubbling up" the error?)

Comment: @user6872907 In Java, a "checked exception" is any exception class which inherits from `Exception` other than those that inherit from `RuntimeException`. When a method throws a checked exception, it must be declared in the `throws` clause of the method signature or caught with a try...catch. Similarly if a method calls an exception which declares a checked exception. See [this tutorial from Oracle](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/exceptions/catchOrDeclare.html) for more details.